# How do I fix wireless for Linux Mint on Sony Vaio M13M1E?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, linux-mint

I have a [Vaio M13 M1E](http://www.sony.co.uk/product/vn-m-series/vpcm13m1e-l), and I'm trying the [Linux Mint 10 (Julia) DVD](http://www.linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=70), via a bootable USB stick created [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/), but the wireless isn't working.

On the other hand, trying [Ubuntu 10.10 Netbook](http://www.ubuntu.com/netbook) it works fine - given that Mint is a variant of Ubuntu, I'd have expected it to work the same.

I've tried searching, but not found anything relevant, so anyone have suggestions on what to try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the 32-bit version (i386) instead of the 64-bit version (amd64) and the wireless works straight away.

Not sure if it's specifically related to this (thought the Atom N470 was 64-bit), or just a coincidence, but it solves the problem for me.